# StateNotifierProvider not keeping state between app restarts

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-state, riverpod

Using [flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.4](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) and testing in the android emulator as well as on a physical device.

What am I doing wrong that the Sign In screen `state` value does not persist in the StateNotifierProvider after a restart of the app?

The accountSetupProvider's `state` defaults to the Intro Screen. After the Intro Screen's onPressed button is clicked the `state` is updated to the Sign In screen and it triggers correctly a rebuild to display the Sign In screen.

However, after a flutter hot restart or opening/closing the app, the Intro Screen, rather than the Sign In screen displays. Shouldn't the `state`, which now is set to the Sign In screen after clicking onPressed in the Intro Screen persist between restarts and cause the Intro Screen to be skipped and the Sign In screen to display?

As you can see below `main.dart` has an initial AppRoutes.**root** route. In `app_router.dart`, this "root" screen opens `root_screen.dart`, which is a `ConsumerWidget` that is `watch`(ing) my StateNotifierProvider called "accountSetupProvider" in `account_setup_provider.dart`.

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.root,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => AppRouter.onGenerateRoute(settings),
    );
  }
}
```

**app_router.dart**

```
class AppRoutes {
  static const String root = RootScreen.id;
  static const String intro = IntroScreen.id;
  static const String signIn = SignInScreen.id;
}

class AppRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final _args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.root:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => RootScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRoutes.intro:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => IntroScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRoutes.signIn:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => SignInScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

**root_screen.dart**

```
class RootScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const RootScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'root_screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final screen = watch(accountSetupProvider.state);

    if (screen == AppRoutes.signIn) {
      return SignInScreen();
    } else if (screen == AppRoutes.intro) {
      return IntroScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

**intro_screen.dart** (only including the `onPressed` portion of intro screen, which I'm expecting to set the state to the new screen, even after a flutter hot restart or app restart.)

```
onPressed: () {
  context
    .read(accountSetupProvider) // see accountSetupProvider StateNotifierProvider below.
    .setScreen(AppRoutes.signIn);
},
```

**account_setup_provider.dart** (inits to the `AppRoutes.intro` screen.)

```
class AccountSetupNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  AccountSetupNotifier() : super(AppRoutes.intro);

  void setScreen(String screen) {
    state = screen;
  }
}

final accountSetupProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AccountSetupNotifier>((ref) {
  return AccountSetupNotifier();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even looking at your code, and looking only at your subject line, it is not at all surprising to me.  "Hot Restart" resets all variables.  How could there be any state preserved?  Are you instead looking for "Hot Reload"?

Comment: What about restarting the app on a physical device then? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of "state"? I'm aware that hot reload keeps state.

Comment: If you want persistent state, you need to write your values to a database or something like https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences.